# Bitwise operations based on two numbers

Tags: bit-manipulation, mask, bit, bitmask

I got an assignment today at my faculty (Mathematics Faculty of Belgrade, Serbia) which says:

1) Write a program that for two given integers x and y, inverts in integer x those bits that match the corresponding bits in y, while the rest of the bits remain the same.

For example:

```
x  = 1001110110101
y  = 1100010100011
x' = 0011101011100
```

I managed to write a program that does that, but I am a little insecure about the quality of my solution. Please, if you have time, check out the code and tell me how I could improve it.

```
int x, y, bitnum;
int z = 0;
unsigned int mask;

bitnum = sizeof(int) * 8;
mask = 1 << bitnum - 1;

printf("Unesi x i y: ");
scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);

while (mask > 1) {
    if ( (((x & mask) == 0) && ((y & mask) == 0)) ||
          ((x & mask) && ((y & mask) == 0)) )
        z += 1;                                   
    z <<= 1;
    mask >>= 1;
} /* <-- THAT'S HOW STUPID PEOPLE SOLVE PROBLEMS... WITH HAMMER! */
z = y~; /* <-- THAT'S HOW SMART PEOPLE SOLVE PROBLEMS... WITH ONE LINE */
```

Everything works correctly, for x = 423 and y = 324 for example, I get z = -344, which is correct. Also, bit prints match I would just like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at your `x`/`y`/`x'` example, it must strike you that `x'` is a complement to `y`. And indeed it's like that.

```
 x  y  x'
 --------
 1  1  0
 0  0  1
 1  0  1
 0  1  0
```

Spoiler (hover your mouse over block below, if you want to see a solution):

> For bits that match, you invert bit in `x`, but as it is the same as bit in `y`, it's the same as inverting bit in `y`. When they do not match, you keep the bit from `x`, what is already inversion of bit in `y` on its own. I hope you can see the one-line solution already yourself: `x' = ~y;`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by smarter... To think I spent half an hour to figure how to do it with bitmask and pushing bits around... *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

//Try with the next code:

unsigned int mask1, mask2, mask3, answ;

mask1 = x & y;          // identify bits with 1 that match

mask2  = ~x & ~y;       // identify bits with 0 that match

mask3 = mask1 | mask2;  // identify bits with 0 or 1 that match

answ = x ^ m3;          // Change identified bits